# Why is My SQL Join duplicating rows in the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I usually deal with "SQl Server 2008" but this database is php myadmin which I'm wondering might be the issue.

I have two very basic tables. One called BOOK and one called CATEGORY.
BOOK has Book_id, title, author,medium
CATEGORY has just book_id and category.

Books can have multiple categories associated with it.

So when I do a simple join like this:

```
SELECT a.title,a.author,b.category 
FROM BOOK a
LEFT JOIN CATEGORY b
ON a.book_id = b.book_id
```

I get duplicate records. So for every book that has one category where I would expect 1 row returned I get 2. Where I would expect 2 rows I get 3 and where I would expect 3 I get 4.

Any help on why this is happening would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please  share sample data

Comment: `CATEGORY` has a key named `book_id`? Strange...

Comment: Your query is good. Your error is not there, it must be on your data. -By the way, your model is maybe not the best, you should change it.

Comment: You may *think* a book has only one category, but it would seem that the `category` table has two rows for the book.

Comment: There really should be a junction table sitting in between `BOOK` and `CATEGORY` for this database. Like @dneoth mentions, `CATEGORY` should not contain `book_id` in it.

Comment: Your database isn't phpMyAdmin, your database is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Something seems afoul in the the structure of these tables.  In a normal case I would imagine that BOOK would have a category_id because a book can only have one category and a category can have many books.  To have a book_id in the CATEGORY table would mean that a category can **only** have one book in it, whereas a book could have many categories.

I would blame not the type of database, but the structure of the tables that are causing your unexpected situation.